# System.ArgumentException: 'An entry with the same key already Exists | For loops and SortedLists

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting the error: System.ArgumentException: 'An entry with the same key already exists.'. This error happens at the line: listSorted.Add("productList(i-1) & productYears(t-1)", GetDemand(i - 1, t - 1)). I want to concatenate each product type (ModelX, ModelY, ModelZ) with each product year (2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), so there's 12 unique keys paired with the 12 unique demand values in the GetDemand() function.

```
Public Class frmDemand

    Dim productList As List(Of String)
    Dim productYears As List(Of String)
    Dim sortedDemand As SortedList(Of String, Integer)
    Dim demandArray As Integer(,)

    Private Function GetDemand() As Integer(,)
        Return {{205, 220, 245, 230},
                   {160, 174, 152, 144},
                   {480, 424, 396, 456}}
    End Function

    Private Function GetProductModels() As List(Of String)

        Dim list As New List(Of String)

        list.Add("ModelX")
        list.Add("ModelY")
        list.Add("ModelZ")

        Return list
    End Function


    Private Function GetProductYears() As List(Of String)

        Dim list As New List(Of String)

        list.Add("2013")
        list.Add("2014")
        list.Add("2015")
        list.Add("2016")

        Return list
    End Function


    Private Function GetSortedDemand() As SortedList(Of String, Integer)

        Dim listSorted As New SortedList(Of String, Integer)


        For i As Integer = 1 To productList.Count + 1

            For t As Integer = 1 To productYears.Count + 1
                listSorted.Add("productList(i-1) & productYears(t-1)", GetDemand(i - 1, t - 1))

            Next

        Next

        Return listSorted

    End Function




    Private Sub frmDemand_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        demandArray = GetDemand()
        productList = GetProductModels()
        productYears = GetProductYears()
        sortedDemand = GetSortedDemand()


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowDemand_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowDemand.Click

        Dim product As String = txtProduct.Text
        Dim year As Integer = txtYear.Text

        Try

            If Not productList.Contains(product) Then
                Throw New Exception("Product does not exist")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Input Error")
        End Try


        Try

            If Not productYears.Contains(year) Then
                Throw New Exception("Year does not exist")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Input Error")
        End Try


        MessageBox.Show("Demand for " & product & " in year " & year & " is " & GetSortedDemand(product & year))

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShowAllDemand_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowAllDemand.Click

        Dim yearsString As String = ""
        Dim demandString As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 1 To productYears.Count + 1
            yearsString &= vbTab & productYears(i - 1)

            For t As Integer = 1 To productYears.Count + 1
                demandString &= productList(t - 1) & vbTab

            Next
        Next



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's way too much code there. The fact that you haven't/can't narrow it down suggests that you haven't taken steps to solve the issue for yourself first. The error message is telling you what the issue is: you're trying to add the same key to your `SortedList` twice. You need to debug the code to find out why that's happening. Before you post here, you should already know at least what value is being added when the exception is thrown and when exactly that same value was already added. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly concatenating the values in this line:

```
listSorted.Add("productList(i-1) & productYears(t-1)", GetDemand(i - 1, t - 1))
```

You are always using `productList(i-1) & productYears(t-1)` as your key.

It should be:

```
listSorted.Add(productList(i-1) & productYears(t-1), GetDemand(i - 1, t - 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed it. But now I get the error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Comment: Fixed it! List.Count returns the number of entries, not the index so I don't need + 1. It all works. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it works, sorry I didn't spot the other problems with your counters. Please consider marking the question as answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.

Comment: I didn't know I could that. Done!